# Using same angular directive with horizontal and vertical layout

Tags: html, angularjs

I have 2 different form engines that share a common over-driven "Question" directive with different input types (select, calendar, multi-line, etc) based on a question type and then I want to display it in one engine like:

QuestionName    InputField

and another

QuestionName

InputField

The goal is to share code with minimum duplication.  Is there a good way to setup the html so it can switch back and forth or do I just move the InputField into it's own directive that can be placed twice in the question directive and show/hide as appropriate.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided on just creating an inner directive for the field portion displayed twice on the question directive using ng-if based on if it should be vertical or horizontal set at the form level.

```
<tr><td>questionname <span ng-if="direction==='vertical'><br /><field-directive /></span></td>
```